# How to share a Dictionary instance in Swift?

Tags: swift, dictionary

According to the Swift Programming Language reference, Dictionary instances are copied whenever they are passed to a function/method or assigned to a constant or variable. This seems inefficient. Is there a way to efficiently share the contents of a dictionary between two methods without copying?

Comment: Can you link to the doc that says this? Also you could just use an NSDictionary instead.

Comment: @68cherries: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ClassesAndStructures.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH13-XID_109

Comment: It seems trying to maintain a pointer to a higher point on a dictionary while your temporary variable goes into its lower levels is way harder than it should be. Never thought I'd have to create a class just to use a pointer!

Answer (score 17):

It's true the documentation says that but there are also various notes saying it won't affect the performance. The copying will be performed lazily - only when needed.

> The descriptions below refer to the “copying” of arrays, dictionaries, strings, and other values. Where copying is mentioned, the behavior you see in your code will always be as if a copy took place. However, Swift only performs an actual copy behind the scenes when it is absolutely necessary to do so. Swift manages all value copying to ensure optimal performance, and you should not avoid assignment to try to preempt this optimization.

Source: [Classes & Collections](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ClassesAndStructures.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH13-XID_109)

Meaning - don't try to optimize before you actually encounter performance problems!

Also, don't forget that dictionaries are structures. When you pass them into a function, they are implicitly immutable, so no need for copying. To actually pass a mutable dictionary into a function, you can use an `inout` parameter and the dictionary won't be copied (passed by reference). <strike>The only case when a mutable dictionary passed as a parameter will be copied is when you declare the parameter as `var`.</strike>

Comment: Sounds like a copy on write? Performance might still be an issue more often when sharing dictionaries. I will do some performance testing to see if this is an issue

Comment: @tony Added some info about `inout` params.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning inout params. I hadn't gotten to that section of the doc yet. It does sound like passing a Dictionary via inout would be more efficient. Unfortunately, it would also allow the method to reassign the argument itself, which isn't exactly what I'd want. 

I liked the distinction between mutable and non-mutable collections in Foundation so I'm just trying to reconcile the differences.

Answer (score 8):

You always have the option to define a custom, generic class with a `Dictionary` attribute:

```
class SharedDictionary<K, V> {
  var dict : Dictionary<K, V>

  // add the methods you need, including overloading operators
}
```

Instances of your `SharedDictionary` will be passed-by-reference (not copied).

Answer (score 7):

I actually talked to someone on the Swift team today about "pass by reference" in Swift. Here is what I got:

1. As we all know, struct are pass by copy, classes are pass by
   reference
2. I quote "It is extremely easy to wrap a `struct` in a `class`.
   Pointing to GoZoner's answer.
3. Even though though a `struct` is copied, any `classes` defined in
   the struct will still be passed by reference.
4. If you want to do traditional pass by reference on a struct, use
   `inout`. However he specifically mentioned to "consider adding in
   another return value instead of using `inout`" when saying this.

Since `Dictionary` defines `KeyType` and `ValueType` as generics:

```
struct Dictionary<KeyType : Hashable, ValueType>
```

I believe this means that if your `KeyType` and `ValueType` are class objects they will not be copied when the `Dictionary` itself is copied, and you shouldn't need to worry about it too much.

Also, the `NSDictionary` class is still available to use!

Answer (score 6):

As other said "Swift only performs an actual copy behind the scenes when it is absolutely necessary to do so." so performance should not be a big problem here. However you might still want to have a dictionary passed by reference for some other reasons. In that case you can create a custom class like below and use it just like you would use a normal dictionary object:

```
class SharedDictionary<K : Hashable, V> {
    var dict : Dictionary<K, V> = Dictionary()
    subscript(key : K) -> V? {
        get {
            return dict[key]
        }
        set(newValue) {
            dict[key] = newValue
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Trust the language designers: the compiler is usually smarter than you think in optimizing copies.

You can hack around this, but I don't frankly see a need before proving it's inefficient.

Comment: According to the docs: "Whenever you assign a Dictionary instance to a constant or variable, or pass a Dictionary instance as an argument to a function or method call, the dictionary is copied at the point that the assignment or call takes place." That doesn't imply that any sort of optimization will take place. Under that assumption, I'm trying to understand how I can efficiently share a dictionary.

Comment: What the docs specify is the programming model. "It behaves as if...". Unless you measured it, you don't know what optimisations are done under the hood. We know from Objective-C that things behave to the outside as described, but internally work quite differently.

Comment: Why would anyone simply trust the language designers to make this sort of thing as efficient as possible? Any good scientist would ask for proof from anyone making a claim. It's in my best interest to assume the language does not have secret hidden features to make my code run faster than what the language docs suggest.